# OneToMany returns 1 result when no result should be returned?

Tags: model, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a two models, the second is mapping to the same first model twice, with specific values (it has the role of a ManyToMany table with added values) :

```
public class ModelB extend Model {
    public ModelA parent;
    public ModelA child;
    public String value;
    public boolean verified = true;
}
```

In ModelA :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="child")
List<ModelB> items;
```

If no entries are in the database for ModelB and I do a `modelA.items.size()` => 1!

Why 1 ? It should be 0.

This results in an error regarding the boolean and some other unexplained.

How can I fix it?

Comment: take from the list first element and tell us what is it. Is it null ? Or is this an object with values ?

Comment: It's an object of ModelB, but with all the field at null. I double checked the database, and the table is empty!

Comment: try setting default value in ModelA: List<ModelB> items = new List<ModelB>();

Answer (score 1):

http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_joinquery.html

It appears that when joining using a "fetch join" as described in the link above, presumably this is the behavior of Ebean currently. However you can work around that by performing a "Query join" for the OneToMany relation like this:

```
List<Order> orders =   
Ebean.find(Order.class)  
    .fetch("customer", new FetchConfig().query())  
    .findList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and was able to solve it by adding an identity column to the secondary table (ModelB). I did not investigate the cause but I suppose Ebean needs a primary key on the table in these kind of situations.